# Writing row name using "index" while exporting files in csv format

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have a list and wish to export it in csv file.
I applied the following codes:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

# Define List
Data = [101, 12, 143]

# Convert to dataframe
df_Data = pd.DataFrame(Data)

# Export to csv file
df_Data.to_csv("Data.csv", header=["Data"] , index=["Row1", "Row2", "Row3"])
```

I am able to rename the column name using "header" option.

However, the row-name doesn't change and is mentioned as such:

[image]

Can somebody please help me out with this in python?

Comment: `index` should be a boolean (`True` or `False`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to not try to change `index` and `column` names in the `to_csv(...)` parameters.

So try using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

# Define List
Data = [101, 12, 143]

# Convert to dataframe
df_Data = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns=["Data"], index=["Row1", "Row2", "Row3"])

# Export to csv file
df_Data.to_csv("Data.csv")
```

Then the output CSV would work as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot @U11-Forward for your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can set column and row names using a list like this.

```
df_Data.columns=['Data']
df_Data.index=['Row1','Row2','Row3']
```